# querying view is taking too much time

Tags: sql, view

We have a view table and selecting from view is normally taking too much time.
for example: `select x,y,z from view1` is taking too much time to load. This one is ok.

If you query: `select x,y,z from view1 where x in ('abc')` queries in seconds.

If you query:  `select x,y,z from view1 where x in (select 'abc' from table1 where y='1234')` queries in seconds.

But if you query:
`select x,y,z from view1 where x in (select x from table1 where y='1234')` is taking too much time to query and this is the problem we want to solve.

By the way you can think that : `select x from table1 where y='1234'`
returns `'abc'` with one row.

The scenario is decsribed above ,
what do you think could be the reason to take so much time to query on the third query.
We have tried joining but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean in your last sentence, "it didn't work"? Did you get an error? Did you fail to get the results required? Did it take as long as your existing query (or longer)? Can you post the definition of your view? Is table1 already used in it? How many different values of x will typically be selected from table1 where y='1234'? What indexes do you have on the tables being used? Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc) is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A view is not some magic piece of time saving code
- A view is a macro that is expanded: no more, no less

So if your view has 5 tables and 4 JOINs, these will be evaluated *every time*.

So, my question should be:

> Is there suitable indexing on the underlying column in some base table that generates column x in the view?

As for your last SQL, you are adding an extra IN clause and subquery to the view contents.
Note that you may know only one row is returned but the optimiser may not because or poor or out of date statistics, and/or bad indexing

My next question

> Does table1 have good indexes to satisfy the subquery efficiently?

Either way, looking at the query plan will help you to identify what is going wrong

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I believe it is related to optimiser behaviour since we have tried almost all possible query methods.

Comment: The optimiser is quite predictable: but using views and not having indexes limits the options it has